# Multiple sub-domain in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I have created an app on app engine and associated it with a domain using Google Apps.It also had one sub-domain running on it.

Today I added two more sub-domains with the "ghs.googlehosted.com" as the CNAME for the domains.
I did a nslookup on the subdomain `nslookup -q=cname test.example.com` and got the following response

```
Server:127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53
Non-authoritative answer:
test.example.com canonical name = ghs.googlehosted.com.
```

Its already been more than 6hours and I am still getting the following error

```
The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

In the logs, I do not see any request coming to appengine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to add the subdomains in your appengine application settings.